# android phonegap non compiled project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I need to modify some classes of phonegap 2.2 for android but supplied sdk contains only .jar file. Is there an available full project in order to rebuild it?

Comment: Why are you modifying those classes? Just inherit those classes in your custom classes and modify the code

Comment: that would be great but how to do it? I am using eclipse and imported .jar library but I am unable to modify it. Maybe a newbie question but never do it before. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the full Android source code for PhoneGap is always available at:

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=summary

Comment: great, that's exactly what I need. I appreciate so much your help.